# Почему базовый класс не инициализируется наследником? SAX

Tags: java, sax

Объявление класса

```
public class SAXPars extends DefaultHandler {...}
```

Вызов функции

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser(); 
SAXPars saxp = new SAXPars();

parser.parse(in, saxp);
```

Метод parse не работает

Сообщает, что нет метода с входными параметрами InputStream, SAXPars

Соответственно не может привести SAXPars к DefaultHandler

Comment: Можете более конкретно проблему сформулировать? Код вполне себе валидный.

Comment: Исправил вопрос, теперь должно быть понятно

Comment: А из какого пакета вы берете DefaultHandler в первом случае? Точно из правильного?

Comment: Да, спасибо в этом и была проблема. import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler; нужно без jdk.internal.